# Change children's opacity without setOpacityCascade in cocos2d-x 3

Tags: cocos2d-x, opacity, alpha, cocos2d-x-3.0

I know setOpacityCascade will cascade the alpha its children, but in that way, all children get that alpha. Therefore, if any children overlaps, the overlapped part will looks weird.

eg.

The red and blue block have the same parent
[image: The red and blue block have the same parent]

What I want when set parent opacity
[image: What I want when set parent opacity]

What I got when set parent opacity
[image: What I got when set parent opacity]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I give last solution first: render your parent `Node` to a `RenderTexture` and work with result `Sprite` as a atomic `Sprite`. that way you can `setOpacity` to newly created `Sprite` and you'll get what you want, but this solution is expensive, let alone its inflexibility.

Comment: Unfortunately, the child nodes actually have a lot of animations going on in the real project and `RenderTexture` is far too slow. I wonder if there's something like a dynamic alpha mask or something alike.

Comment: You may be able to do that with original shader.